# Build R GUI with Xcode 7 and OS X 10.10.4

Tags: r, xcode, bigdata, analytics, osx-yosemite

Hi I'm new with R and I'm trying to compile and build R GUI with XCode 7 and Yosemite (10.10.4) but I have this error

```
My Mac runs OS X 10.10.4, which is lower than R’s minimum deployment target. Change your project’s minimum deployment target or upgrade My Mac’s version of OS X.
```

How can I change the minimum deployment target in that project?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked here: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac

Answer (score 0):

This message appears if your project's OS X Deployment Target is set higher than one of the project's dependencies can support.

Go to your project settings, and set `OS X Deployment Target` to a value that's no greater than 10.10.4 (so basically 10.10) and it should work.